# Terraform: aws_lambda_permission reaching The final policy size (20718) is bigger than the limit (20480)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

## Context:

I have a  lambda named `console` that allows me to run all cron-like tasks using PHP Symfony's console command. As my codebase is a big monolith that's why I have only one lambda (having one lambda by command would still require 99.9% of the code and would be a nightmare to deploy)

This lambda is invoked by cloudwatch events , with basically 1 cloudwatch rule => 1 task

As we also have unrelated cloudwatch rules, I want to be sure that only the appropriate rules can invoke this lambda. I.e I don't want to just allow all cloudwatch rules.

With terraform we manage it like that

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "console" {
   # not relevant
}

# These 3 resources  are repeated  N times for each "task"
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "run_task_foobar" {
  # not relevant
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "run_task_foobar" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.run_task_foobar.name
  target_id = "foobar"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.console.arn
  input     = "\" console run foobar \""
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "run_task_foobar" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.console.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.run_task_foobar.arn

  # not compatible with tags
}
```

## The problem

As we have several dozen of task , 53 to be exact , we now have this error when we try to apply for a 54th task

> PolicyLengthExceededException: The final policy size (20701) is bigger than the limit (20480).

And yes when I check in the AWS Console , I can see the resulting IAM Policy is HUGE

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "foo",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxx:function:console",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:xxxxx:rule/foo"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "bar",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxx:function:console",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:xxxxx:rule/bar"
        }
      }
    },
    ... # repeated 53 times
```

Of course it becomes clearly obvious that the `Condition` block should be factorized into the pseudo code

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "bar",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxx:function:console",
      "Condition": {
        "InArray": {  # I don't know if inarray exists but it does not matter see below
          "AWS:SourceArn": [
               "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:xxxxx:rule/bar",
               "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:xxxxx:rule/foo",
               ... , # 53 times
           ]
        }
      }
    },
```

However there's no fine grain control on "Condition" , it's autogenerated by both terraform and the AWS console

### Question(s) :

1. Is there an actual way to factorize this ?
2. Is there an alternate solution by creating directly an IAM policy ?

My current workaround would be to setup a convention that all the cloudwatch event rule should start with "console-"  so that I can use a wildcard , but that seems fragile ?

Comment: If having a lambda for each command would result in having 99% of the code in each lambda sounds like that code should be refactoring out to a lambda layer that can be used by each if the tasks then each task lambda has just it's own stuff

Comment: the problem is that it's a monolith, so it's not like there's a clear cut. Also it would still be a deployement nightmare,  we are in continuous deployment, and today our flow is just  1.  zip the code  2.  upload to s3    3. call aws lambda update,  4.  no 4th step .  Your proposal would require to create/update the lambda layer (how would that work for a php application?), and when we merge something into master, to redeploy the lambda layer 53 time, and to know which of the 53 lambda limitation. also need update of their code.

Comment: Hello, 

Not sure if this could work, but there's this operator:

`"Condition": {"ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {}}`

Comment: @eexit , unfortunately, the condition is not written by me ,  hence my comment "However there's no fine grain control on "Condition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current context your only option is as you already stated the use wild cards in the policy construction as this AWS article also advocates https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-resource-based-policy-size-error

Regarding your security concerns around the fragility related to the usage of wildcards, if you have proper security controls in this AWS account, meaning IAM write permissions are only accessible to a restricted set of users/automations you will be fine.